# sql grouping columns

Tags: sql, group-by

Suppose I have 3 columns like this:

```
Status, QName, Item
Broken, q1, i1
Broken, q1, i2
Broken, q1, i3
Broken, q2, i4
Broken, q3, i5
Immediate,q1,i6
Immediate,q2,i7
```

I want output like this:

```
Status = Broken, No of queues = 3, total items = 5
Status = Immediate, No of queues = 2, total items = 2
```

How can I get this output in a single query?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for this:

```
Select    Status,
          Count(Distinct QName) As NoQueues,
          Count(Distinct Item) As TotalItems
From      YourTable
Group By  Status
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT Status,
       COUNT(DISTINCT QName) [No of queues],
       COUNT(DISTINCT Item) [total items]
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY Status
```